# Typescript Generic Base On Subclass Type

Tags: typescript

Assume that there are two classes:

```
class A<I> {
  inner: I;
  setInner: () => Partial<I>;
}

class B extends A<B['inner']> {
  inner = {
    data1: 123,
    data2: '123',
  };
  setInner = () => {
    return { data1: 456 };
  };
}
```

I want the class A to regulate that all its subclasses' "setInner" function can only return the partial of its own inner object and with the same types. The above code is acceptable, but I still want to remove the generic of A when extends ( the "A<B['inner']>" ), because if I need more than one inner properties and many class Bs, it will be like:

```
class B1 extends A<B1['inner1'], B1['inner2'], B1['inner3'], ...> {...}
class B2 extends A<B2['inner1'], B2['inner2'], B2['inner3'], ...> {...}
class B3 extends A<B3['inner1'], B3['inner2'], B3['inner3'], ...> {...}
class B4 extends A<B4['inner1'], B4['inner2'], B4['inner3'], ...> {...}
```

So each time I want to copy a class B or add a inner property, I have to modify the whole A<B1['inner1'], B1['inner2', B1['inner3'], ...>, which is annoying.

Is there any way to define something like 'this' in class A but refers to the object instance of subclass B? Or is there any approaches to make class B simpler even with a very complex class A, because there might be hundreds of B but only one A.

Comment: You could maybe try binding the function in your subtype's constructor? Could you provide an example of what it is exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: I'm trying to achieve something similar to ReactJS. The class A can be regarded as React.Component and class B can be regarded as my own component. The 'inner' and 'setInner' are similar to 'state' and 'setState'. In development, I will create hundreds of components, like class B1, B2, B3, B4.... Each component will have its own inner type, and setInner should be used to change the inner without breaking the type.

Comment: Normally you would add a generic constraint for a common interface over I and then define setInner in A around that (Even if it's just like for a Object or something... Right now for example it could just be another primitive or a function, so it needs that type information). But what I think it is you're trying to achieve is probably easier without using generics at all.

Comment: Indeed, I thought as a super class, class A should be able to regulate the behavior of functions for all subclass, but it seems that using generic is already the simplest way for now.

Answer (score 0):

I found it's able to put the subclass as a generic of the superclass:

```
class A<Sub extends { inner1?: any; inner2?: any }> {
  setInner1: () => Partial<Sub['inner1'];
  setInner2: () => Partial<Sub['inner2'];
}
class B extends A<B> {
  inner1 = { key: 123 };
  inner2 = { key: 'abc' };
  setInner1 = () => ({ key: 456 }); // This works
  setInner2 = () => ({ key: 123 }); // This gives an error
}
```

In this way, when adding inner properties to class, it's not required to change ever subclass file, and the code is also short.